# XSLT's XAML XMLNS

Tags: html, xaml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying tp transform a XAML document such as this

```
<Section xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xml:space="preserve" TextAlignment="Left" LineHeight="Auto" IsHyphenationEnabled="False" xml:lang="en-us" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="User" NumberSubstitution.Substitution="AsCulture" FontFamily="Arial" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FF000000" Typography.StandardLigatures="True" Typography.ContextualLigatures="True" Typography.DiscretionaryLigatures="False" Typography.HistoricalLigatures="False" Typography.AnnotationAlternates="0" Typography.ContextualAlternates="True" Typography.HistoricalForms="False" Typography.Kerning="True" Typography.CapitalSpacing="False" Typography.CaseSensitiveForms="False" Typography.StylisticSet1="False" Typography.StylisticSet2="False" Typography.StylisticSet3="False" Typography.StylisticSet4="False" Typography.StylisticSet5="False" Typography.StylisticSet6="False" Typography.StylisticSet7="False" Typography.StylisticSet8="False" Typography.StylisticSet9="False" Typography.StylisticSet10="False" Typography.StylisticSet11="False" Typography.StylisticSet12="False" Typography.StylisticSet13="False" Typography.StylisticSet14="False" Typography.StylisticSet15="False" Typography.StylisticSet16="False" Typography.StylisticSet17="False" Typography.StylisticSet18="False" Typography.StylisticSet19="False" Typography.StylisticSet20="False" Typography.Fraction="Normal" Typography.SlashedZero="False" Typography.MathematicalGreek="False" Typography.EastAsianExpertForms="False" Typography.Variants="Normal" Typography.Capitals="Normal" Typography.NumeralStyle="Normal" Typography.NumeralAlignment="Normal" Typography.EastAsianWidths="Normal" Typography.EastAsianLanguage="Normal" Typography.StandardSwashes="0" Typography.ContextualSwashes="0" Typography.StylisticAlternates="0">
<Table CellSpacing="1" Margin="0,0,0,0"><Table.Columns><TableColumn Width="264" /></Table.Columns><TableRowGroup><TableRow><TableCell Padding="0,0,0,0">
<Paragraph FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="10.666666666666666" Margin="0,0,0,0">
   <Span FontWeight="Bold"><Run>some text</Run></Span><Run> </Run>
   <Span Foreground="#FF00681C"><Run>some more text</Run></Span>
</Paragraph>
</TableCell></TableRow></TableRowGroup></Table>
</Section>
```

into HTML

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

but the results are blank

I've suspected it's due to an absent namespace declaration in the XSLT, but the ones I've added haven't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSL works. It gives this,

```
<html xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
   <body>


      some text 
      some more text



   </body>
</html>
```

**HTML output:**

```
some text some more text
```

See this too,

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
   <xsl:output method="html"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">  
<html>
    <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
   <body>


      some text 
      some more text



   </body>
</html>
```

**HTML output:**

```
some text some more text
```

Comment: right. seems it was my software being it less than clear on the conversion steps :)